# PostgreSQL hstore, json C# Visual Studio implementation

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio

Is there any way to implement PostgreSQL special data types as hstore, json etc. for C# in Visual Studio 2015?

When I try to Update model from database, it sees only columns with primitive data types, but I need one of those mentioned above to import from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json type as written in documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html